# python pandas, unicode decode error on read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When importing a csv file I am getting an error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15: invalid start byte`

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-99e71d524b4b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py', wdir='C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3')

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 500, in <module>
    M5()

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 221, in M5
    s3 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"S3.csv", sep=",") #encode here encoding='utf-16

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1139, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1995, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 991, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1123, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1176, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1299, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1315, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert

  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1553, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15: invalid start byte
```

What i've tried:

```
`s3 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"S3.csv", sep=",", encoding='utf-16')`
```

I get error `UnicodeError: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`

What can be done to get this file to be read properly?

Comment: The supposed duplicate has absolutely nothing to do with Unicode parsing errors. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `s3 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"S3.csv", sep=",", encoding='Latin-1')`

Mostly encoding issues arise with the characters within the data. While utf-8 supports all languages according to pandas' documentation, utf-8 has a byte structure that must be respected at all times. Some of the values not included in utf-8 are latin small letters i with diaeresis, right-pointing double angle quotation mark, inverted question mark. This are mapped as 0xef, 0xbb and 0xbf bytes respectively. Hence your error.

Comment: thank you , it worked. Can you explain why?